# OpenCV - Android : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to capture an image from the JavaCameraView and load the captured image into another activity and is supposed to be processed (Hough Circles).

```
private void takePhoto(final Mat rgba) {

    // Determine the path and metadata for the photo.
    final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final String appName = getString(R.string.app_name);
    final String galleryPath =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    final String albumPath = galleryPath + File.separator +
            appName;
    final String photoPath = albumPath + File.separator +
            currentTimeMillis + LabActivity.PHOTO_FILE_EXTENSION;
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, photoPath);
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            LabActivity.PHOTO_MIME_TYPE);
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, appName);
    values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, appName);
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, currentTimeMillis);

    // Ensure that the album directory exists.
    File album = new File(albumPath);
    if (!album.isDirectory() && !album.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create album directory at " +
                albumPath);
        onTakePhotoFailed();
        return;
    }


/*
    // Try to create the photo.
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
    if (!Imgcodecs.imwrite(photoPath, mBgr)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to save photo to " + photoPath);
        onTakePhotoFailed();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Photo saved successfully to " + photoPath);
 */




    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    Mat cannyEdges = new Mat();
    Mat lines = new Mat();


    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, mBgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR, 3);
    //Converting the image to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mBgr, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Imgproc.Canny(grayMat, cannyEdges, 10, 100);

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(cannyEdges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, 50, 20, 20);

    Mat houghLines = new Mat();
    houghLines.create(cannyEdges.rows(), cannyEdges.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    //Drawing lines on the image
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.cols(); i++) {
        double[] points = lines.get(0, i);
        double x1, y1, x2, y2;

        x1 = points[0];
        y1 = points[1];
        x2 = points[2];
        y2 = points[3];

        Point pt1 = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point pt2 = new Point(x2, y2);

        //Drawing lines on an image
        Imgproc.line(houghLines, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }



    //Converting Mat back to Bitmap
    Utils.matToBitmap(houghLines, currentBitmap);

    Log.d(TAG, "Photo saved successfully to " + photoPath);







    // Try to insert the photo into the MediaStore.
    Uri uri;
    try {
        uri = getContentResolver().insert(
                Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to insert photo into MediaStore");
        e.printStackTrace();

        // Since the insertion failed, delete the photo.
        File photo = new File(photoPath);
        if (!photo.delete()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete non-inserted photo");
        }

        onTakePhotoFailed();
        return;
    }

    // Open the photo in LabActivity.
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LabActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(LabActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_URI, uri);
    intent.putExtra(LabActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_DATA_PATH,
            photoPath);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The error occurs after i click the capture option.

```
12-07 00:15:45.420    9205-9933/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8672
Process: com.example.alexies.cameratesting, PID: 9205
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null
        at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:122)
        at org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(Utils.java:132)
        at com.example.alexies.cameratesting.MainActivity.takePhoto(MainActivity.java:380)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentBitmap` is `null` in your code.

Either you didn't copy the part where it's assigned a bitmap value or it's never assigned. If there's some part of your code missing please add it in your question, if not, your problem is that you never get the bitmap.

### EDIT

You never initiate `currentBitmap`. The [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20Bitmap%29) state that the provided bitmap must be the same size as the `Mat` object (your `houghLines`) and the [type of your bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) should be `ARGB_8888` or `RGB_565`.

Comment: here is the whole MainActivity.class http://pastebin.com/WqBLtqaR  and this is the onCreate() of my LabActivity class http://pastebin.com/WYze8KHn

Comment: @alexies I've edited the answer. You never initiate `currentBitmap` but it should be a bitmap with the same size as the `Mat` you provide to the function.