# OpenCV-Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null error

Tags: java, android, opencv, illegalargumentexception

I got this error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null

I referred this link

[OpenCV - Android : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119826/opencv-android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bmp-null)

So I made code like this.

> inputBitmap.createBitmap(matInput.cols(), matInput.rows(),
>   Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

And this is my code related to Bitmap

```
private ImageView imageView_matInput;
private ImageView imageView_matResult;
private Mat matInput;
private Mat image_matches;
Bitmap myBitmap = null;
Bitmap inputBitmap = null;
Bitmap resultBitmap = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    matInput = new Mat();
    image_matches = new Mat();

    imageView_matInput = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_matInput);
    imageView_matResult = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_matResult);

    File imageFile = new File(Global.imageFileName);

    if(imageFile.exists()) {
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d(TAG, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    processingImage();


}

public void processingImage() {

    Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap, matInput);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(matInput, matInput, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    surfWithFlann4(matInput.getNativeObjAddr(), image_matches.getNativeObjAddr());

    Imgproc.resize(image_matches, image_matches, matInput.size());

    inputBitmap.createBitmap(matInput.cols(), matInput.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(matInput, inputBitmap);
    resultBitmap.createBitmap(image_matches.cols(), image_matches.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(image_matches, resultBitmap);

    imageView_matInput.setImageBitmap(inputBitmap);
    imageView_matResult.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
}
```

Global is a Class that has a path of a image taken by camera.

matInput is not null and surfWithFlann4 is a native function that compares a picture taken by camera to images from **asset** directory.

The `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null` error occured in here

> Utils.matToBitmap(matInput, inputBitmap);

Comment: cross check that your bitmap is not null

Comment: @VivekMishra bitmap is null and mat is not null

Comment: If bitmap is null, it will cause issue

Comment: I solved this. inputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(matInput.cols(), matInput.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);